# Can an object with uninitialized fields be safely added in std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, language-lawyer, constexpr

In the following program, default constructor of struct `A` does not initialize its field `v`. Then in a constant expression, `std::vector<A>` is emplaced with `A()` object:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct A {
  constexpr A() noexcept {}
  int v;
};

constexpr bool f() {
    std::vector<A> as;
    as.reserve(1);
    as.emplace_back();
    return true;
}
static_assert( f() );
```

MSVC compiler complains about the reading of uninitialized variable:

```
<source>(14): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
<source>(11): note: failure was caused by a read of an uninitialized symbol
<source>(11): note: see usage of 'A::v'
```

But both GCC and Clang are fine with the program. Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/addx11aTT

Which compiler is correct here?

Comment: I don't see where value of `v` is read in this code (as reported by the message) -- just conjecturing here, perhaps it is an interaction with MSVC debug-build code to detect uninitialized access?

Comment: @M.M I believe it is somewhere in reallocation part of the vector

Comment: @Dmitry there cannot be any reallocation of vector containing objects that exist, in this exact program

Comment: `as.emplace_back();` returns an unused reference to the appended `A` object. And that contains an uninitialized value.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not the shown program is well-formed (which I think it is), in order to "safely" use this construction one must not perform any operation on `std::vector` that might copy/move the indeterminate value. So no modifications except decreasing capacity, increasing capacity only from empty state, and adding/removing elements at/from the end (if capacity is free). No copying of the vector itself either.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like MSVC is reporting a read error. Apparently by evaluating then discarding the returned reference form `emplace_back()` rather than just discarding it. MSVC does demonstrate a bug in a simplified version. See below.

The problem isn't allocation in vector, it's that the `emplace_back()` is a method that returns an expression, a reference to the added element.

This can be also seen by the following which creates an A object, provides a reference to it, then, when the reference is evaluated it causes an error in MSVC. It should not, as @user17732522 pointed out in comments. It should be discarded as an unused lvalue.

```
struct A {
    constexpr A() noexcept {}
    int v;
};

constexpr bool f() {
    A a;
    A& b = a;
    // b;   // uncommenting this causes MSVC to fail
    return true;
}
static_assert(f());

int main() {}
```

Compiles fine but if the `b`, a reference to the objects is evaluated this error ensues:

```
Message     failure was caused by a read of an uninitialized symbol
```

This is a MSVC bug.

Comment: And why would `b;` cause a read? This looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: @user17732522 reading an uninitialized value is UB. And `b` is an expression that gets evaluated even if not used.

Comment: But evaluating `b` doesn't cause any read. It is a lvalue expression to which no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied.

Comment: @user17732522 it's an expression that is the value of the object `b` refers to. That is `a`.

Comment: The lvalue result of the expression is the object `a`, not the value of the object (which would be a prvalue). No value of `a` is read.

Comment: `b` is an [id_expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.id#unqual-1)

Comment: Yes and it has value category "lvalue" (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.id#unqual-2.sentence-7) and it is also a [_discarded-value expression_](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr#context-2.2) which specifically has the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied only if its type is `volatile`-qualified (which it isn't here). The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion followed by temporary materialization is what would read the value of `a.v` via the implicit copy constructor.

Comment: @user17732522 Yep. You're right!  I didn't realize these were discarded. The only time I have ever used something like that was with volatile in embedded apps. Thanks for following up on my boneheaded understanding.